# delphi пример работы IPC плохо работает

Tags: delphi

нашел вот такой пример работы, сервер и клиент IPC 
http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/sources/system/2012-year/ipc.html

Но работает не корректно, точнее программы запускаются, но данные не передаются.
Возможно проблема в коде, текст приходит пустой на сервер, пример кода приема с сервера:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerRecieveIpcData(Sender: TObject; var ClientName: WideString; var ClientWaitingForResponse: Boolean; var Data: Pointer);
var
  ResponseData: TResponseData;
begin
  // TData(Data^).Text - пустоту возвращает
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(ClientName + ': ' + TData(Data^).Text); 
  if ClientWaitingForResponse then
  begin
    lstrcpynW(ResponseData.Text, PWideChar(Edit1.Text), MAX_LENGTH);
    if not IPCServer.SendIpcData(ClientName, @ResponseData, SizeOf(TResponseData)) then
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Error send response - ' + SysErrorMessage(IPCServer.LastError));
  end;
end;
```

теперь на клиенте отправка

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: TData;
  ResponseData: Pointer;
begin
  ResponseData := nil;
  Data.ProcessId := GetCurrentProcessId;
  lstrcpynW(Data.Text, PWideChar(Memo1.Text), MAX_LENGTH);
  if not IPCClient.SendIpcData('IPC Server', @Data, SizeOf(TData), CheckBox1.Checked, 1000, ResponseData) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Error send IPC data - ' + SysErrorMessage(IPCClient.LastError));
  if ResponseData <> nil then
  begin
    MessageBeep(0);
    MessageBoxW(0, TResponseData(ResponseData^).Text, 'IPC Client', 0);
  end;
end;
```

вобщем приходит на сервер пустота, да еще и если запросить ответ, то ошибка выскакивает

делаю на delphi 6 нужно именно на ней

итого я на клиенте отправляю строку 1234567890
а получаю (дебаг переменной):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

куда то девается два первых символа и заменяются...

Comment: опечатка, нужно IPC

Comment: Если на delphi 6, то почему P**Wide**Char(Memo1.Text), и  юникодные функции используются?

Comment: чем можно заменить? функция требует именно это 
[Error] Unit_Client.pas(66): Incompatible types: 'Array' and 'PWideChar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для D6 попробуйте вот что:

```
var
   WS: WideString;

....
WS := Memo1.Text;
lstrcpynW(Data.Text, PWideChar(WS), MAX_LENGTH);

на приёме
WS :=  TData(Data^).Text;
Memo1.Lines.Add(ClientName + ': ' + WS);
```

Comment: Можно без промежуточной переменной: `PWideChar(WideString(Memo1.Text))`

Comment: Пусть лучше так следит за содержимым

Comment: вобщем я сейчас попробовал, результат тотже) но заметил, что при передаче, почему то первые 2 символа меняются, на "=" и пустоту 
и поэтому при получении, он получает только = .... вот в этом проблема

Comment: хотя я передаю целиком строку 1234567890
вот что получается http://prntscr.com/l7504e

Comment: добавил картинку в вопрос

Comment: вобщем я понял, что отправляет он как то неверно указатель, потому что при получении номер процесса больно длинный, а так он обычно 4х значный. что это значит? на картинке видно

Comment: Освойте WM_COPYDATA, как вам в другой теме советовали

Comment: его уже освоил) вобщем разобрался сам, дело было в этом модуле IPC  закомментил строку // FreeMem(Data); и все стало как надо

Comment: Но с Widestring  всё равно актуально, т.к. D6 не юникодная.